# Colourize an image in canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I was wondering if there is a way to draw an image but give it a colourized effect.

If you consider games, when you want to place a sprite but theres an object in the way, often the object you try to place get a red tint to it to indicate it cannot be placed which is what im trying to achieve.

I currently draw it with an opacity here:

```
ctx.globalAlpha = 0.5                   
ctx.drawImage(image,abposx,abposy);
```

Is this possible to achieve without a library?

Comment: you can use jquery plugins to achieve this. What they do in those plugins is just manipulating the image data in canvas.

Comment: jQuery is NOT the answer, given it does not do much for canvas elements. And i already got the answer to this in april 2012...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can draw a semitransparent rectangle over top of it. For example:

```
ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)'; // 1/2 opacity red
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 30, 30); // Draw this over top of your image
```

[Here's a demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/5TAuK/)

<del>For isometric images, all you have to do is create the appropriate path. Here's an example of that:</del>

You can clip the overlay to your image by setting the `globalCompositeOperation` to `source-atop`:

```
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-atop';
ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)'; // 1/2 opacity red
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 30, 30); // Draw this over top of your image
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
```

[Here's a demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/5TAuK/3/) You may also have to use a shadow canvas if the areas you're trying to draw on also have content, though.

Comment: Wouldn't i need to set its width/height of fillRect to image width height or it will cover the entire canvas?

Comment: @Dave: You'll need to set its width, height and position appropriately, yes.

Comment: Hmm not sure this is going to work fully due to it being isometric angle, it'll inevitably make the alpha pixels red as well =/

Comment: @Dave: You can make the appropriate path and fill it instead.

Comment: I don't follow what you mean by path?

Comment: Ah i see - hmm so theres no way to just give an image a red tint to it most of my sprites have random shapes, like trees etc

Comment: @Dave: Well, you can actually set the compositing mode. Hold on, I'll add that to the demo.

Comment: Thanks :) I will have a try with this!

Comment: Do i still require : g.fillRect(mouseX - 15, mouseY - 15, 30, 30);

Comment: @Dave: No, that's just for the demo, you'll want to change that to match your actual image's position and dimensions.